# Passing cursor variables as a parameter into a procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm not sure if I am making the cursor correct or if its the way I am passing each record from the cursor as a parameter into the procedure. It is not returning any variable saying no data was found
**Script:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

ACCEPT v_custcity PROMPT 'Enter a city'

DECLARE 
    CURSOR customers IS
    SELECT custname from customer
    WHERE custcity = UPPER('&v_custcity');
    
    v_totalcars NUMBER;
    v_moneyspent NUMBER;
    v_abstotcars NUMBER;
    v_absmoneyspent NUMBER;
    v_tab   CHAR(1):= CHR(9);
    
BEGIN
    FOR v_cname IN customers LOOP
        getcars(v_cname.custname, v_totalcars, v_moneyspent);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cname.custname || v_tab || v_totalcars || v_tab || v_moneyspent);
        v_abstotcars := v_abstotcars + v_totalcars;
        v_absmoneyspent := v_absmoneyspent + v_moneyspent;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total cars in city:' || v_tab || v_abstotcars || v_tab || 'Total money spent:' || v_tab || v_absmoneyspent);
END;
/
```

**Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getcars (
    v_customername   IN    saleinv.custname%TYPE
    , v_totalcars    OUT   NUMBER
    , v_moneyspent   OUT   NUMBER
) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(sale.carserial)
    , round(SUM(sale.carsaleprice + serv.partscost + serv.laborcost), 2)
    INTO v_totalcars, v_moneyspent
FROM
    saleinv   sale
    FULL OUTER JOIN servinv   serv ON sale.custname = serv.custname
    WHERE sale.custname = v_customername
GROUP BY
    sale.custname;
END;
/
```

I get an error saying:

**Error report -**

**ORA-01403: no data found**

**ORA-06512: at "S5_BACHELLI.GETCARS", line 8**

**ORA-06512: at line 14**

**01403. 00000 -  "no data found"**

**Cause:    No data was found from the objects.**

**Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.**

Comment: Are you sure that every customer in the particular city has a row in the `sale` table (and is `custname` really the key in both tables?  That's rather weird)?  If you can have customers without sales, which seems reasonable, your procedure ought to catch the `no_data_found` exception and return whatever you want to return in that case (0 or NULL).

Comment: Should customer and sale are different tables, should I be running a join on the cursor for the custname? but yes custname is the common key for both tables

Comment: It depends on your requirements.  You could define the cursor to only return customers in the city with sales (though I'd use an `exists` rather than a `join`).  It would make more sense to me to allow the procedure to accept any customer and return some default value if the customer has no sales.  But I don't know what your requirements are.

Comment: the value I am accepting when prompting has over 100 customers related to the city in the customer table so I know there are values, I have run just the select statement separately and got results. I am just not sure why I can't pass each name through the loop with the cursor

Comment: But do each of those 100+ customers have a sale?  Have you called your procedure manually for each individual customer?  Realistically, at least one of the customers returned by your cursor does not have a sale so the `select` statement in your procedure returns no rows.  Like I said initially, you probably want to catch the `no_data_found` exception in your procedure and return some sensible value.

Comment: That makes sense, I will give it a try

Comment: Not sure entirely how to implement the exception or where to put it. wanted to try this in the for loop but the when gets underlined `EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
        CONTINUE;`

Comment: Given the FULL OUTER JOIN, I would expect to see some COALESCE / NVL in the WHERE and GROUP BY to handle the unmatched rows, as well as to treat NULLs for missing data as zero within the SUM.